# Referencing non static variable from within static Inner Class

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes, nested-class

I need to reference a variable of a top level class from a method within a static class.

This method should act on unique instances of the top level class and so it feels like I shouldn't instantiate the top level class inside the static class.

Basically I want something like

```
public class TopLevel{
   // private
   int innerV

   public static class Inner implements X {
     for(i=0; i<innerV,i++){
         doSomething 
     }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to just say `this.innerV` or something similar in the `for` loop and similar places?

Comment: Have you tried to actually write this and compile it?

Comment: Please review my edit - I have corrected the code formatting. Ty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a `static` inner class, you can't refer to (nonstatic) members of the outer class directly. If you remove the static qualifier, it will work, because instances of nonstatic inner classes are implicitly tied to an instance of the containing class, so they can refer to its members directly.

Declaring your inner class `static` removes this link, so you need to either pass an instance of the outer class to the inner class method (or its constructor) as a parameter, or create it inside the method.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way around this. There are some problems with removing "static" for my specific application....will try to figure it out. Thanks for letting me know there's no cheat solution though!

Answer (score 2):

You **can't do that**. Create a TopLevel instance and if you make an innerV accessor (getter/setter) or make it public, than you can.

```
public class TopLevel {
   public int innerV

   public static class Inner implements X {
     for(i=0; i<innerV,i++){
         TopLevel tl = new TopLevel()
         tl.innerV = 12345678;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside: don't you need to assign t1.innerV before the for loop?

Comment: Yes something like that. Java defaults to zero for ints so it compiles but the loop never gets executed btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because it doesn't make sense, any more than referring to a non-static member from a static function makes sense. There is no current instance of the outer class in the context of the static inner class to get the instance variable from.